# using values from a reactive input to directly input into a custom function

Tags: r, function, shiny

The following function fails:

```
get_num <- function(input$num){ans <-input$num 
                          return(ans)}
```

since R is confused by the `$` symbol.

Although this is a toy example, I would like to write a function that directly takes reactive input values (in this case, a number) and does something meaningful with them, without having to preempt the situation with

```
num <- input$num
get_num <- function(num){ans <-num 
                          return(ans)}
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three points here:

1. when you are dealing with reactive values, you use `reactive()` instead of `function()` in your script.

Here is example:

```
num_square = reactive({input$num^2})
observe(print(num_square()))
```

The first line defines a new reactive values base on `input$num` and second lines print it as soon as it changes. Note that reactive values are same as function, and you should call them with `()` in front of them.

2. when you want to save a value to outside environment (other that internal use of function or reactive) you should use `<<-` instead of `=` or `<-` notation.

Here is an example:

```
reactive1 <- reactive({num_square <<- input$num^2
          print(num_square) })
```

The above line changes the value of `num_square` as soon as you run `reactive1()` some place in your code. note that without running `reactive1()` the value of `num_square` wont change. This is the BIG DIFFERENCE between `reactive()` (lazy evaluation) and `observe()` (eager evaluation).

3. `observe()` is another method to use reactive values in a function. ***It seems to me that you are looking for this one.***

Here is an example. The value of `get_num` will change as soon as you change input$num in your program.

```
observe({get_num <<- input$num
         print(get_tmp)})
```

Note that above script should be in middle of `shinyServer(function(input, output) { ... })`.

---

Difference between `reactive()` and `observe()`: [refer to: http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/observe.html ]

> An observer is like a reactive expression in that it can read reactive
>   values and call reactive expressions, and will automatically
>   re-execute when those dependencies change. But unlike reactive
>   expressions, it doesn't yield a result and can't be used as an input
>   to other reactive expressions. Thus, observers are only useful for
>   their side effects (for example, performing I/O).
>
> Another contrast between reactive expressions and observers is their
>   execution strategy. Reactive expressions use lazy evaluation; that is,
>   when their dependencies change, they don't re-execute right away but
>   rather wait until they are called by someone else. Indeed, if they are
>   not called then they will never re-execute. In contrast, observers use
>   eager evaluation; as soon as their dependencies change, they schedule
>   themselves to re-execute.

Comment: ok thanks. To keep things clean I am going to delete my comments and invite you to do the same. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
get_num <- function(ans = input$num) {
  out <- seq(ans:ans*2)
  return(out)
}

get_num()
```

or:

```
get_num <- function(ans) {
  out <- seq(ans:ans*2)
  return(out)
}

get_num(input$num)
```

Comment: A small expalanation perhap's

Answer (score 0):

I think a more natural way to do this in shiny is to use `reactive` like so:

```
get_num<-reactive({ ans<-input$num)}
```

Obviously you could do more, like:

```
 get_num<-reactive({ans<-input$num*20
                    ans<-ans/pi
 })
```

or whatever. Then refer to your value as `get_num()` as it is now a function.