# Shiny UI Module Issue: server module not updating choices with reactive expression

Tags: r, module, shiny, reactive

I am having a lot of trouble getting a search filtering module working.

I am to run stats on a large database of cat owner information.
I want my search module to bring up a list of possible owners(that the user can select from)  based on a selection from a list of cat breeds.
I thought wrapping the updateSelectInput with observe and using a reactive cat owner expression would facilitate this, in the module, but it is not working( and I can't guess why this is happening or how to debug this). It worked in these other posts([1]:[R shiny passing reactive to selectInput choices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21465411/r-shiny-passing-reactive-to-selectinput-choices) , [2]:[using values from a reactive input to directly input into a custom function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26789243/using-values-from-a-reactive-input-to-directly-input-into-a-custom-function))

Why won't my selectInput update with cat owners?

```
library(shiny)
df=data.frame(
  cat=c("tabby","DSH","MSH","LSH","DSH","MSH","LSH","sphinx"),
  owner=c("Foo","Bar","Bash","Foo","Foo","Foo","Bar","Bash"),stringsAsFactors = F)
refinedSearch<-function(input, output, session){
  ownsCat<-reactive({df[df$cat%in%input$cat,"owner"]})
  observe({updateSelectInput(session, "ownerSelected",
                             label ="Owned By",choices = ownsCat())})
  return()
}
refinedSearchUI<-function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  fluidRow(
    column(4,selectInput(ns("cat"),"Cat",selectize = T, 
                         choices =c("tabby","DSH","MSH","LSH","sphinx") )),
    column(4,selectInput(ns("ownerSelected"),"Owned By","",selectize = T))
  )
}
ui <- fluidPage(
  h1("Find cats owners"),
  fluidRow(column(10,offset=1, refinedSearchUI("tmp"))),
  fluidRow(column(10,offset=1, actionButton("addFilter","Add a Filter",
                                            icon = icon("plus"))))
)
server <- function(input, output,session) {
  refinedSearch(input,output,session)
  observeEvent(input$add, {insertUI(selector = "#addFilter",where = "beforeBegin",
                                    ui = refinedSearch(input,output,session))})
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thank y'all for you time.

Comment: Edit(typo): replace refinedSearch(input,output,session) refinedSearch("tmp")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be quite a bit of confusion on how to call modules. You need to use the `callModule()` function in the server. Also, when inserting UI (using the `insertUI()`function), you need to call the `refinedSearchUI()` function, not the `refinedSearch()` function (which, again, should always be called through `callModule()`, so it should never actually get called directly like that).

I'd recommend a re-reading of [the modules article](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html).

You also have a typo. The event in your `observeEvent()` function should be `input$addFilter`, not `input$add` (which doesn't exist, so that observer is never fired..)

If you change your server function to this, your app will work as expected:

```r
server <- function(input, output,session) {
  callModule(refinedSearch, "tmp")

  observeEvent(input$addFilter, {
    id <- paste0("filter_", input$add)
    insertUI(selector = "#addFilter",where = "beforeBegin",
             ui = refinedSearchUI(id))
    callModule(refinedSearch, id)
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ms.Borges!  Your feedback was on point. I am new to module use in shiny.